# End of script output before headers error with Python Script

Tags: python, xampp

I've read multiple SO posts regarding this, but can't seem to get this to work. This is my first time working with Python on Apache so I would appreciate the help I can get!

So ultimately, I'm trying to run a Python script in my htdocs, but I can't seem to just get the simple python script running on XAMPP. I keep getting a 500 error:

[image: error]

**myurl.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print ("""
    <TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
    Hello, world!
"""
)
```

Comment: try replacing the first line with print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

Comment: @MadisonCourto I tried replacing it and it didn't help

Comment: @Sam Check out the error log written by Apache. It will give you more information about exactly what caused the 500 error. It's usually stored somewhere like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @RobBricheno [Tue Nov 20 17:49:06.593901 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 47854] [client ::1:50462] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py' failed: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py
[Tue Nov 20 17:49:06.595547 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 47854] [client ::1:50462] End of script output before headers: myurl.py

Comment: @RobBricheno it seems like I don't have the correct permissions right? how do I change that?

Comment: @Sam chmod 777 myurl.py - to at least test if it is a permission issue

Comment: @Sam Right! You probably need to give execute permissions on the python file to the user under which apache is running. If you're on a debian-based system that's normally www-data. You can see which user is being used in the output of `ps aux`

Comment: Using the command @MadisonCourto will work too, but will give everyone full permissions on your python file. That might be fine if this is just going to be a development system or you are the only user. In a real deployment it may present a security risk.

Comment: @RobBricheno I completely agree, but it's a quick solution to test if it is indeed a permission issue

Comment: @RobBricheno it doesn't seem to be a permission issue. I tried the command Madison suggested in my terminal, but now the error seems to be different.

Comment: [Tue Nov 20 17:59:04.720816 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 48715] [client ::1:50555] AH01215: python3: No such file or directory: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py
[Tue Nov 20 17:59:04.720884 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 48715] [client ::1:50555] End of script output before headers: myurl.py

Comment: The file does indeed exist though... so I'm not really understanding why that error would exist

Comment: That means that `env` can't find `python3` in your system. Can you run `python3` by hand from the command prompt? Does `/usr/bin/python3` exist? If so, you could try changing the first line of your script (the *shebang* line) to read `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @RobBricheno when I run` python3` by hand, it seems to exist but when I type in `/usr/bin/python3` it says no such file or directory exists

Comment: You can find the correct path to python3 using the command `which python3`. Then try using that complete path in the first line of your script.

Comment: It worked! Thank you @RobBricheno

Comment: No problem, I hope you have a lot of fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the discussion, there were multiple problems here, which were solved by examining the `error.log` written by apache and then making appropriate changes.

The first error was:

> [Tue Nov 20 17:49:06.593901 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 47854] [client
>   ::1:50462] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py' failed:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py [Tue Nov 20
>   17:49:06.595547 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 47854] [client ::1:50462] End
>   of script output before headers: myurl.py

The relevant part here is:

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py' failed
```

Permissions needed to be set on the `.py` file being executed to allow the user running the apache process to execute the script. This was done using `chmod`.

Then, another error was presented:

> [Tue Nov 20 17:59:04.720816 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 48715] [client
>   ::1:50555] AH01215: python3: No such file or directory:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myurl.py [Tue Nov 20
>   17:59:04.720884 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 48715] [client ::1:50555] End
>   of script output before headers: myurl.py

The relevant part is:

```
python3: No such file or directory
```

This shows that the system could not find a `python3` binary to execute. The correct path to the `python3` interpreter had to be determined using `which python3`. This was then edited into the shebang line of the script.