# How to solve internal error 500 for python on Xampp

Tags: python, macos, terminal, xampp, python-3.8

I am getting this error:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: End of script output before headers: python.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

192.168.64.2 Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d PHP/7.4.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I have done the following:

Added .py to Addhandler in httpd.conf

[image]

I have also installed pip and pymysql.

I am using python 3.8.3

I have also have the permissions set to chmod 755

[image]

have also tried chmod 755, +x but no luck I have also checked the error logs but no clear problem

In the error logs it says: `End of script output before headers: python.py`

and

`(2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py' failed: /opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py`

btw I am using Mac

Heres my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/local/env python3
print ('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print ('\r\n')
print ()
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('Hello Python')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

Comment: Never post code or configs as pictures please, paste them in a code block :) Same goes for logs, stack traces, error messages, chat history, information etc etc. Anything that's text essentially. The odd exception of graphical user interface errors from linters or terminal behavior and such.

Comment: Another question do we use `Content-type` or `Content-Type`

Comment: What? Could you elaborate? At least HTTP 1.1 standard allows for `CoNtEnT-tYpE` as the key if you will, altho that's not preferred and most people use `Content-Type`as it's easier on the eyes. But I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i was asking with of the "content-type" is prefered

Comment: There is no "preferred", they're all welcome. And that's not what this question is about is it? Also, add the apache error log (relevant peaces) to your question (in a code block).

Comment: I was just thinking that might have been the problem

Comment: Check your error logs, as they should tell you what's wrong. Also check your web browsers debug console as it should state which headers are recieved (Ctrl+Shift+J in chrome, and check under the "network" tap as that's where headers for each request will pop up. It should say which `contenT-tYPe` was parsed ;)

Comment: error logs state this: `End of script output before headers: python.py`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402670/end-of-script-output-before-headers-error-with-python-script

Comment: my full error is this: `[Mon Jun 01 00:15:32.246014 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 845] [client 192.168.64.1:49572] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py' failed: /opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py` and `[Mon Jun 01 00:15:32.246945 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 845] [client 192.168.64.1:49572] End of script output before headers: python.py`

Comment: And there you have it, Apache is trying to execute `/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py` but it doesn't exist (because you've placed it elsewhere). And this is why it's important to check the log files not just the console errors :)

Comment: But it is in 11-python folder and does exist.

Comment: In /Users yes, but not /opt it seams.

Comment: so then how could I solve it?